# Can't log on to 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have installed (and re-installed)12.04 on to a rather elderly computer which was running XP.
Installation completes OK but each time after the restart and entering my username and PW, I get a prompt 
d@d-desktop:~$ and can get no further.
I'm not very technical!

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu! :-) Could you please describe the steps you perform until you reach that prompt in a bit more detail? Thank you!

Comment: Which edition of Ubuntu did you install? It's not the server edition, is it?

Comment: The graphical server is failing to start - probably due to missing drivers for something.. the d@d-desktop means you are user 'd' & have called your PC 'd-desktop' & is a prompt in a terminal environment (ie you have to type in commands, like 'cmd' in Windows [only much more comprehensive]. If you type in `startx` it will produce pages of text telling how it went - this will contain the error report, and may offer clues.

Comment: typing "startx" might get the gui desktop to start... might want a lighter desktop / wm, like xfce (Xubuntu, mint xfce), lxde (Lubuntu), or even something like crunchbang (though it's not based on ubuntu anymore, I think)

Comment: are you using either nvidia or ati graphics or is it intel?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have 3d capabilities, so you must choose a different desktop environment.

**First,**

to install a different desktop, execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel
```

**Next,**

navigate up and down the list using the arrow keys. Select or un-select a desktop using the <kbd>space</kbd> bar. Do not select "live DVD", select a type of "desktop".

Select "[Xubuntu desktop](http://xubuntu.org/)", "[Lubuntu desktop](http://lubuntu.net/)", or both.

Do not select the "ubuntu desktop" and if it is selected, un-select it.

**Finally,**

press <kbd>tab</kbd> to navigate to "ok" and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Use the following command to return to the login screen:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

or, use this command to reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

---

**Alternatively,**

you can start over and reinstall ubuntu with an alternative desktop using any one of these official images.

[Download Lubuntu (designed to run on older computers with little ram / iso will fit on a cd).](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso)

[Download Xubuntu (designed to use minimal resources).](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/trusty/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-i386.iso)